# how to solve npm ERR! code E404 in vuejs when using datepicker

Tags: javascript, vue.js, npm, datepicker

I'm very new to Vue.js and now I'm trying to use vue.js datepicker from  https://ly525.github.io/material-vue-daterange-picker/guide.html#introduction

but when I import the script to use, I get this message

> 'VMdDateRangePicker' is declared but its value is never read.ts(6133)
>   Could not find a declaration file for module 'v-md-date-range-picker'.
>   'd:/IG
>   Group/report_dashboard/issue-reporting-frontend(backup)/node_modules/v-md-date-range-picker/dist/v-md-date-range-picker.cjs.js'
>   implicitly has an 'any' type.   Try `npm install
>   @types/v-md-date-range-picker` if it exists or add a new declaration
>   (.d.ts) file containing `declare module
>   'v-md-date-range-picker';`ts(7016)

I've tried using command `npm install @types/v-md-date-range-picker`
But I get this message:

> npm ERR! code E404 npm ERR! 404 Not Found - GET
>   https://registry.npmjs.org/@types%2fv-md-date-range-picker - Not found
>   npm ERR! 404 npm ERR! 404  '@types/v-md-date-range-picker@latest' is
>   not in the npm registry. npm ERR! 404 You should bug the author to
>   publish it (or use the name yourself!) npm ERR! 404 npm ERR! 404 Note
>   that you can also install from a npm ERR! 404 tarball, folder, http
>   url, or git url.

how to solve this problem?

Comment: Are you using TypeScript?

Comment: I'm not using TypeScript

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
npm config set registry http://registry.npmjs.org
```